# Consulta por parte no SQL cláusula IN

Tags: sql, while, procedure, job

Eu tenho que fazer uma consulta com mais de **400 mil** registros na cláusula `IN`. Acontece que não posso fazer tudo de uma vez pois posso travar o sistema da minha empresa. Então tenho que rodar em um horário especifico e a cada **5 mil** por vez. Porem desconheço de uma forma eficaz de fazer isso. Queria fazer uma JOB, mas teria que fazer muitas JOBS.

Eu consigo fazer um `WHILE` para que ele rode de 5 mil em 5 mil?  Uso o **SQL Server**.

Comment: você nao consegue substituir o IN por um JOIN/LEFT ?

Comment: Não consigo Andreia, eu vou colocar cerca de números de telefone no where e vou extrair informações desses números. Mas se eu colocar tudo, a operação na empresa pode parar.

Comment: Você tem uma lista de 400.000 telefones e precisa fazer uma ação em cima deles ? O problema ficou pouco claro ao menos para mim.

Comment: se voce puder colocar um exemplo ou uma imagem fica mais facil de visualizar seu problema..

Comment: Olá @RicardoB tive uma situação parecida com uma tabela de pedidos, na minha situação eu criei uma nova tabela apenas com os campos que me eram uteis e utilizei na consulta, e essa nova tabela eu carrego os novos dados gerados na original a cada 1h através de uma JOB, apenas a carga inicial eu realizei na madrugada para não correr risco, apesar de ter sido "INSERT/SELECT", já o prazo de execução da JOB você que irá escolher o que melhor se encaixar. É só uma ideia que você pode testar.